# How can I add a new column to a pre-existing MS Access database table in runtime and save it?

Tags: vb.net

I'm using the visual studio community edition 2019, making a windows application. Using MS access 2013 as my database. I need to add user defined columns to a per-defined table. Also, need to save those columns in database for further use. How do I do this?

I used the ADD function, but nothing happens.

'Database control - DbaseDataSet
'Table name - Topic_Attn

'tried this

Dim newcolumn as string

newcolumn = inputbox("Column header")

DbaseDataSet.Tables("Topic_Attn").Columns.Add(newcolumn)

DBaseDataSet.Tables("Topic_Attn").AcceptChanges()

Comment: [ALTER TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/alter-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql).

Comment: AcceptChanges modifies the table in memory; you need to write the changes out to the database, as suggested by using DoSQL or an ALTER TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly, the attached MS Access DB to apply it in practical, on this link:

[enter link description here](https://www.mediafire.com/file/28ydlm804aa1vg7/AddanewcolumnMSAccessDB.rar/file)

Here is the main code for your question:

Private Sub CmdAddanewcolumnMSAccessDB_Click()

DoCmd.Close acTable, "Emp"

DoCmd.RunSQL ("Alter table Emp Add Column " & TxtColName.Value & " Text")

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

I hope this helps you 
^_^

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. But, I need to alter the database from my visual basic application, which has to be saved.